# Twitter recent images: Where are the thumbnails?

Tags: twitter, images

In the past, when I clicked on a Twitter user's "Recent Images", I could see the thumbnails of all their uploaded images in a horizontal or grid view. I cannot see the thumbnails anymore. Where are they?

Comment: It seems that view is no longer available.

Comment: Any idea if it's temporary or permanent?

Comment: I’d say it’s permanent, since there is no mention of them on the [help page](https://support.twitter.com/articles/20169409-about-user-galleries), but I’m just speculating, as I couldn’t find anything related.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a gallery of a Twitter user's posted images and videos at the following URL:

```
https://twitter.com/{username}/media/grid
```

Replace `{username}` with their handle and you'll see all with thumbnails.